# What git GUI tool on Windows and Mac

Tags: windows, osx, git

What git GUI tool would you recommend for Windows and Mac?

I have tried SourceTree.  While I find it nice, it crashes every once in a while.  Anyone would suggest something instead and why?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: That is a great summary of git GUI clients.  I wish it had some user rating or comments, too

Answer (score 4):

For a cross platform git GUI you could try [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/):

- Cross-platform
- 100% standalone, i.e. just install it and it runs (you don't have to even install git).
- Built in merge tool
- Free (Gratis) but closed source (possible non-free pro version in the pipeline)
- GitHub & BitBucket integration.
- Keyboard Shortcuts

[image: Screenshot of it running]
[image: The keyboard shortcuts]
[image: An example of the Light Theme]

Comment: Now one need an account for using the application, and they have separated out some functionality in an "Pro" version, that you even have to pay a monthly fee to use.. :(

Answer (score 3):

[TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) is a good one for Windows.  It integrates into the context menu and allows you to right-click on files/folders and perform Git operations.  It also overlays icons so you can see at a glance the status of files and folders.  TortoiseGit has useful displays and graphs of the revision history.  Unfortunately, TortoiseGit is not available for Mac.

Of course, as was mentioned above, there are [other GUI's](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I've always gotten on well with Atlassian's SourceTree.

https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree

It's very 'native' and works well with git / hg.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for alternatives, although Atlassian SourceTree not bad at all.

Comment: SourceTree seems to work fine, but some of the releases/updates have varying number of bugs/quirks.. the latest one seems to be doing nothing when you add lots of files, there is absolutely no feedback about what is going on when you stage many files..

Answer (score 0):

Fork is my favourite and it's free! It's got a great gui as well

https://fork.dev/

[image: Fork]